# Synthesis rules for this procedural assignment (combinational circuit)

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, synthesis, asic

I am a noob asking elementary questions. So bear with me.

If I have the following code, what would the synthesis result be if it can be synthesized at all. will the synthesizer generate intermediate variables to facilitate the computation?

```
reg [3:0] a;

always @(*)
begin
   a = -a;
   a = a <<1;
end
```

Comment: No, because the computation makes no sense. What hardware would you expect a statement like `a = -a` to represent? How would you expect it to behave if you turned it on? Remember, not everything you can write in an HDL is synthesizable.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = -a     ;
a = a << 1 ;
```

Both these statements inside the combinatorial `always` block are not valid for synthesis at least on an FPGA, because of its unpredictable nature. It has the same signal `a` as input and output, i.e., you are feeding back the combinatorial output `a` to its own input.

This cannot be simulated as well because it will trigger the `always` block infinite times and the simulator won't be able to resolve the final value in its simulation time interval.

This is called a [Combinatorial Loop](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Implementation/What-is-quot-combinational-loop-quot/td-p/1141622) and Synthesiser should warn you for this. You should avoid this in RTL.

Comment: I thought the OP would see the obvious, here. There's not even a simulation time delay; just nothing. In any case, excellent answer. +1

Comment: I was thinking that synthesizer may be able to replace rhs with intermediate variables during compilation stage, just like variable renaming during compiler stage for C programming

Comment: No, my advice is try not comparing HDLs like Verilog/VHDL with Software Languages like C. Both serve for entirely different purposes. @hardware noob

Comment: Kindly accept the answer as solution if it solved your question, so that it helps others in future. @hardware noob